# Stack level too deep errors occuring in rspec after adding an extra example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm using `ruby-1.9.3-p0`. My bundle includes

```
Using rails (3.1.3)
Using rspec-core (2.7.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.7.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.7.0) 
Using rspec (2.7.0)
Using rspec-rails (2.7.0)
```

I have this very weird problem occurring in my spec. I have about 5 examples, like so:

```
describe "Example" do
  context "when adding stuff" do
    it "should do stuff" do
      # ...
    end

    it "..." do
      # ...
    end
  end

  context "when doing other stuff" do
    it "..." do
      # ...
    end

    it "..." do
      # ...
    end

    it "..." do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

However, if I add an extra example, within the `context "when doing other stuff"` block, I get this error

```
  1) Example when adding stuff should do stuff
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     stack level too deep
     # /../../activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/duration.rb:55


  2) Example when adding stuff should do stuff
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     stack level too deep
     # /../../activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:266
```

What makes this weird is if I comment out everything within the block like so

```
it "should do stuff" do
  # everything commented out
end
```

it still happens. And even if I comment out the new example I added

```
it "new example within when doing stuff context" do
  # everything commented out
end
```

it still throws the error as well. **And then, if I comment out all the code within each example, it still happens!** Only if I remove the first `it "should do stuff"` example entirely, it goes away. Has anyone experienced this? Thanks.

EDIT: One more thing I'd like to add. When running all specs like so:

```
rspec
```

All my examples pass and run with no stack overflow occuring. However, it's only if I run the spec solo is this happening:

```
rspec spec/models/example_spec.rb
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got a method calling itself somewhere (which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself...), or a recursive method that's not hitting its exit condition soon enough, causing a stack overflow. Look through other code you've recently added, or code that code calls and you'll likely find the source of the problem.

Comment: But why would just simply adding an extra example (even blank) be causing a stack overflow. Why not before?

Comment: I don't know. Can you post your actual code instead of pseudo code? Not to be a jerk, but if you give us theoretical code, we can only give you theoretical answers, you know?

Comment: Yea I understand, sorry, I will try to add more context soon. However, I just discovered that running all my specs via `rspec` causes no stack overflow, but running the spec individually does?

Comment: If you're running RSpec v2, I would always run them via `rspec`, not `spec`.

Comment: I had something like this once because of bad method naming. (had a name which is used in rspec)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work Axsuul?  I'm having the exact same issue.  Tests will run but if I add another test even if the code is commented out or flagged as pending I get the error.  

Delete the test all together and they pass.

Comment: @jacklin Yea not sure what was causing that. I just got around it by adding blank tests. Hasn't happened to me on new projects though.

Comment: Our issue was with some problems in a gem that a team member had customized.  Thanks Axsuul!

Comment: Kindly share your model file example.rb

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to check your model for recent changes like

```
after_save :do_something

def do_something
 self.update_attribute(:att,val)
end
```

aka endless loops